# What are the necessary jars for a stand-alone java application calling EJB in glassfish?

Tags: jakarta-ee, netbeans, glassfish, ejb

1. I installed the bundle Netbeans 8 + Glassfish 4
2. I made and EJB delployed in GF
3. I made a stand-alone application which is geting datas from the EJB

I added the folowing jars :

- gf-client.jar
- glassfish-naming.jar
- glassfish-corba-orb.jar
- internal-api.jar

And everything work fine as long as I am runing the stand-alone application in netbeans !

But when I run it from outside netbeans I get this error :

> java.lang.noClassDefFoundError : org/glassfish/internal/api/Globals

MY QUESTION : how do I know the list of jars I need for my application ?

Here is the code :

```
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import packageApp.SessionBeanSingletonInterface;

.....


    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.enterprise.naming.SerialInitContextFactory");
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialHost", "localhost");
    // glassfish default port value will be 3700,
    props.setProperty("org.omg.CORBA.ORBInitialPort", "3700");
    InitialContext ctx;
    try {
        ctx = new InitialContext(props);
        SessionBeanSingletonInterface bean = (SessionBeanSingletonInterface) ctx.lookup("packageApp.SessionBeanSingletonInterface");

        System.out.println(bean.getMessage());

    } catch (NamingException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(JavaApplicationUsingEJB.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

Comment: try `appclient -client` <your client> for a work-around.  see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25943022/remote-glassfish-ejb-module-execution-namingexception-lookup-failed